# Minimize Outlook Appointment Item

Tags: c#, outlook, add-in, appointment

I'm creating a new Outlook ribbon with the ability to create new meeting/appointment invites. The customer is requesting the ability to minimize the new appointment window, but the button is currently disabled and the focus cannot be moved from the window. Is there a way to either enable the minimize button or alter the focus away from the appointment window?

```
Outlook.Application outlook = new Outlook.Application();
Outlook.AppointmentItem appointment = (Outlook.AppointmentItem)outlook.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olAppointmentItem);
appointment.ReminderSet = true;
appointment.BusyStatus = Outlook.OlBusyStatus.olBusy;
appointment.ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = 15;
appointment.Duration = 30;
appointment.MeetingStatus = Outlook.OlMeetingStatus.olMeeting;
appointment.Display(true);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The .Display function of the AppointmentItem takes one parameter. It was set to "true" which I assumed was to display the form. The "true" was actually the modal option being activated. Removing the "True" from the Display() function solved this issue.